# Automating a process - open multiple web forms, fill them in from an excel file

Tags: excel, csv, automation

I have a daily task of filling out some web forms manually (approximately 25 at a time) using a combination of autofill, copy and paste and lots of ctrl + tab. I'm wondering if it would be worth my while learning how to automate this. I've done some coding a few years ago but I'm very rusty. I've got no idea what language would be best but I'm thinking maybe python? Is this something a very inexperienced coder could pick up?

Answer (score 1):

If you are actually interested in learning, it shouldn't be too hard to get started with this.

Python is a good start because there are a lot of libraries that can make tasks like reading from an excel/csv file possible in a few lines of code. For browser automation there is a project called Selenium quoting from their website

`Primarily, it is for automating web applications for testing purposes, but is certainly not limited to just that. Boring web-based administration tasks can (and should!) be automated as well.`

For that they provide libraries for multiple languages(including python) which lets you automate actions in your actual browser window.

You could take a look at their docs and see from there if you think this makes it easy enough to automate your tasks.

https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#introducing-webdriver

Comment: Brilliant, just what I wanted to hear! Thanks so much for your help!